# Visualizing simulation results of a project

Tags: performance, r

I am having some performance problems with a little R script of mine that I use to visualize simulation results of a [project of mine](https://github.com/mapa17/Eruliaf). It now takes longer on my machine to run the R script than the simulation itself, and I guess I am doing something wrong.

```
library(ggplot2)  
DownloadTime <- function(data, prefix) {
    pIds = unique(data$Pid)
    nPeers = length(pIds)

    type <- 1:nPeers
    downloadTime <- 1:nPeers

    for(i in 1:(nPeers)){           
        type[i] <- toString(unique(data[ (data$Pid == i), ]$Type))
        start <- unique(data[ (data$Pid == i), ]$Start)
        lastRound <- max(data[ (data$Pid == i), ]$Tick)
        end <- data[ (data$Tick == lastRound) & (data$Pid==i), ]$End
        if( end >= 0){
            downloadTime[i] <- end - start  
        } else {
            downloadTime[i] <- -1
        }
    }
    pData <- data.frame(type, downloadTime )

    hist = ggplot(pData, aes(x=downloadTime, fill=type)) + 
           xlab("Download time [ticks]") + ylab("Peers") + 
           geom_histogram(position=position_dodge()) + 
           opts(title="Download time") + 
           scale_fill_hue( name="Peers", 
                breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") )
    density = ggplot(pData, aes(x=downloadTime, colour=type)) + 
              xlab("Download time [ticks]") + 
              ylab("Peers [ratio]") + geom_density() + 
              opts(title="Download time") + 
              scale_colour_hue( name="Peers", 
                 breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") )

    path = paste(prefix, "downloadTime_hist.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path , plot=hist , dpi=100)

    path = paste( prefix, "downloadTime_den.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot=density , dpi=100)

    return(pData)
}

proccessData <- function(data, prefix)
{
    maxTick = data$Tick[length(data$Tick)]
    tick <- 0:(maxTick*2-1)
    type <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    online <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    completed <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    avgnTFTSlots <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    avgnOUSlots <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    upRate <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    downRate <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    type <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    tftouUpRatio <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    tftouDownRatio <- 1:(maxTick*2)
    shareRatio <- 1:(maxTick*2)

    for(i in 0:(maxTick-1)){

        tick[i*2 + 1] <- i
        type[i*2 +1] <- "Peer"
        online[i*2 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer"), ] )
        completed[i*2 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End != -1), ] )
        avgnTFTSlots[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$TFT )
        avgnOUSlots[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$OU )
        downRate[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$Download/data[(data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$MaxDownload )
        upRate[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$Upload/data[(data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$MaxUpload )
        tftouUpRatio[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$tftouUpRatio )
        tftouDownRatio[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$tftouDownRatio )
        shareRatio[i*2 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End == -1),]$shareRatio )


        tick[i*2+1 + 1] <- i
        type[i*2+1 + 1] <- "Peer_C1"
        online[i*2+1 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1"), ] )
        completed[i*2+1 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End != -1), ] )
        avgnTFTSlots[i*2+1 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$TFT )
        avgnOUSlots[i*2+1 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$OU )
        downRate[i*2+1 + 1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1) ,]$Download/data[(data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$MaxDownload )
        upRate[i*2+1 + 1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$Upload/data[(data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$MaxUpload )
        tftouUpRatio[i*2+1 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$tftouUpRatio )
        tftouDownRatio[i*2+1 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$tftouDownRatio )
        shareRatio[i*2+1 +1] <- mean( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer_C1") & (data$End == -1),]$shareRatio )
    }

    pData <- data.frame(tick, type, online, completed, avgnTFTSlots, avgnOUSlots, upRate, downRate, tftouUpRatio, tftouDownRatio, shareRatio )

    #Generate Plots
    cm = scale_color_manual( name="Peers (without seeders)", breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") , values=c("red", "blue") )
    pData.upload = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=upRate, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("Ratio") + opts(title="Upload usage") + cm 

    pData.download = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=downRate, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("Ratio") + opts(title="Download usage") + cm

    pData.shareRatio = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=shareRatio, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("Ratio") + opts(title="Download / Upload") + cm 

    pData.tftouUpRatio = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=tftouUpRatio, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("Ratio") + opts(title="TFT/OU Upload") + cm
    pData.tftouDownRatio = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=tftouDownRatio, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("Ratio") + opts(title="TFT/OU Download") + cm

    pData.connPlot = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_area(aes(y=online, fill=type) , alpha=0.4 , position=position_identity() ) + geom_line( aes(y=completed, colour=type) ,position=position_identity()) + ylab("Peers") + xlab("Ticks") + opts(title="Total and completed Peers") + scale_fill_manual( name="Total Peers", breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") , values=c("red", "blue") ) + scale_color_manual( name="Completed Peers", breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") , values=c("red", "blue") )
    pData.ouPlot = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=avgnOUSlots, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("OU Slots") + opts(title="Average number of OU Slots") + cm
    pData.tftPlot = ggplot(pData, aes(x=tick) ) + geom_line(aes(y=avgnTFTSlots, colour=type) ) + xlab("Ticks") + ylab("TFT Slots") + opts(title="Average number of TFT Slots") + cm


    #Save Plots 
    path = paste(prefix, "Connections_OU.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path , plot=pData.ouPlot, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "Connections_TFT.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path , plot=pData.tftPlot, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "Peer_Count.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path , plot=pData.connPlot, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "uploadRatio.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot = pData.upload, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "downloadRatio.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot=pData.download, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "shareRatio.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot=pData.shareRatio, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "tftouUpRatio.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot=pData.tftouUpRatio, dpi=100)

    path = paste(prefix, "tftouDownRatio.png", sep="_")
    ggsave(file=path, plot=pData.tftouDownRatio, dpi=100)


    return(pData)
}


#Generate a copy of an vector v, with elment e insert at position pos ( index starting from 1 ) , pos = -1 appends e to the end
insert <- function(v, e, pos)
{
    if( pos == 1){
        return( c(e,v) )
    } else {
        if( pos > length(v) | (pos == -1) )
            pos = length(v)

        if( pos == length(v))
            return( c(v,e) )
        else
            return( c(v[1:(pos-1)],e,v[(pos):length(v)]))
    }
}

#Script has to be called like : Rscript Statistics.R  [STATS_FILE] [OUTPUT_DIR] [SUMMARY_FILE] [PREFIX] OR [SUMMARY_FILE] [SUMMART_OUTPUT_DIR] [PREFIX]
#Whereby STATS_FILE points to the csv input file and PREFIX will be

#Check arguments ( argument TRUE will filter all system arguments )
arg = commandArgs()

writeLines( paste("Received " , length(arg) , " arguments", sep="") )
writeLines( paste("Received args ... ", arg, sep="") )
#Own arguments start with arg[6]

if(length(arg) < 9){
    writeLines( "Missing arguments!" )
    #quit("no")
}

#writeLines("Enough arguments!")
#writeLines(paste("arg[6] ", arg[6], sep=""))

if( length(arg) == 8 ){
    dataFile = arg[6]
    outputDir = arg[7]
    prefix = arg[8]
    outputDir = paste( outputDir, prefix, sep="/")
    ecdfFile = paste( outputDir, "ECDF.png", sep="")
    histFile = paste( outputDir, "histogram.png", sep="")
    writeLines( "Assuming script was called to generate summary statistics!" )

    #Load data
    data = read.csv(dataFile, comment.char='#', sep=';', header=F )

    #Set col names
    colnames(data) <- c("Type", "DownloadTime")

    #Create plot and store file
    hist = ggplot(data, aes(x=DownloadTime, fill=Type)) + xlab("Download time") + ylab("Peers") + geom_histogram(position=position_dodge()) + opts(title="Download time") + scale_fill_hue( name="Peers", breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") )
    ggsave(file=histFile, plot=hist , dpi=100)

    #Create ECDF
    data.reduced = data[data$DownloadTime != -1, ] #Remove peers that did not complete their download
    #Adds a ecdf column to the data, containing the ecdf value for each line
    #Note: the ddply is used to group the data depening on the Type coloum ( so is like generating two tables, calculating ecdf for each and than join them again)
    data.reduced <- ddply(data.reduced, .(Type), transform , ecdf = ecdf(DownloadTime)(DownloadTime) )
    data.ecdf = ggplot(data=data.reduced) + geom_step(aes(x=DownloadTime, y=ecdf, color=Type) ) + xlab("Download Time") + ylab("ECDF") + opts(title="Download time") + scale_color_hue( name="Peers", breaks=c("Peer", "Peer_C1"), labels=c("BT","BT_ext") )
    ggsave(file=ecdfFile, plot=data.ecdf , dpi=100)
}

if( length(arg) == 9)
{
    dataFile = arg[6]
    workingDir = arg[7]
    histFile = arg[8]
    prefix = arg[9]
    writeLines( paste("Assuming script was called to generate simulation statistics! On statistic data ", dataFile, " with histfile ", histFile , " and prefix ", prefix ,sep="") )

    setwd(workingDir)

    #Load data
    data = read.csv(dataFile, comment.char='#', sep=';', header=F )

    # Log format <Tick> <peer Type> <id> <downloadStart> <DownloadEnd> \
    #<Max Upload Rate> <Max Download Rate> <Current Upload Rate> <Current Download Rate> \
    #<Total # of max TFT Slots> <Total # of max OU Slots> <Total # of used TFT Slots> <Total # of used OU Slots>\n"

    #Name data
    colnames(data) <- c("Tick","Type","Pid","Start","End","MaxUpload","MaxDownload","Upload","Download","MaxTFT","MaxOU","TFT","OU","TFTDown","TFTUp","OUDown","OUUp" )

    #Calculate averages
    data$upUsage <- data$Upload / data$MaxUpload
    data$downUsage  <- data$Download / data$MaxDownload
    data$shareRatio <- data$Download / data$Upload
    data$tftouUpRatio <- data$TFTUp / data$OUUp
    data$tftouDownRatio <- data$TFTDown / data$OUDown

    #Remove irregularities , NaN and inf are set to zero
    data[ is.nan(data$tftouUpRatio),]$tftouUpRatio = 0
    data[ is.nan(data$tftouDownRatio),]$tftouDownRatio = 0
    data[ is.nan(data$shareRatio),]$shareRatio = 0
    data[ is.infinite(data$tftouUpRatio),]$tftouUpRatio = 0
    data[ is.infinite(data$tftouDownRatio),]$tftouDownRatio = 0
    data[ is.infinite(data$shareRatio),]$shareRatio = 0

    #Filter too high values
    m = mean(data$shareRatio) * 10
    data = data[ ((data$shareRatio) < m),]
    m = mean(data$tftouUpRatio) * 10
    data = data[ ((data$tftouUpRatio) < m),]
    m = mean(data$tftouDownRatio) * 10
    data = data[ ((data$tftouDownRatio) < m),]

    #Do processing and generate Plots
    proccessData(data, prefix)
    pData = DownloadTime(data, prefix)

    #Save the processed data into the summary file
    write.table(pData, file=histFile, sep=";", 
                append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, 
                row.names = FALSE)
}
```

The heavy lifting is done in `processData()`. I think the problem is either the `for` loop itself or the condition based filtering on the data table.

Comment: Oh, didnt know about something like this existing. Is there a way to move the question?

Comment: Try these tips first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474941/636656

Comment: @user - if you want, you can flag the question for a moderator to move it for you. Alternatively, I'd recommend paring your question down and focusing it on a specific part of your code that isn't performing optimally. `?Rprof` can help identify which parts of your code are slow. Having some sample data to go with it will also encourage others to try and help! Here's the guide to making a great question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Good luck!

Comment: Too much code. But you should read *The R Inferno* to get awesome tips on speeding up your loops: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of code to wade through. But after a quick look at your `processData` function, some things stand out.

```
# This part:
online[i*2 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer"), ] )
completed[i*2 +1] <- nrow( data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer") & (data$End != -1), ] )
# etc ...

# Can be replaced with this:
d <- data[ (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer"), ]
online[i*2 +1] <- nrow( d )
completed[i*2 +1] <- nrow( d[(data$End != -1), ] )
# etc...


# And yet again replaced with this:
idx <- (data$Tick == i) & (data$Type=="Peer")
online[i*2 +1] <- sum(idx)
completed[i*2 +1] <- sum( idx & (data$End != -1) )
# etc...
```

..The basic idea here is to avoid doing the same calculation many times. Extracting data from a data.frame is rather costly, and you seem to only need the number of matches. Indexing using a logical expression will produce a TRUE/FALSE vector, and the rows extracted are the TRUE values, so summing the index vector is the same as the row count...